# Netplan not creating route for interface

Tags: networking, netplan

I am trying to setup an ipip6 tunnel between a remote machine and a local one in order to give my machine a public IPv4 address (It has IPv6, but it is behind a carrier grade NAT).

So far I have been able to get this working by manually running a series of `ip` commands.

On my local machine (machine A) I run the following commands to get the tunnel set up:

```
sudo ip link add name tun0 type ip6tnl local [machine A ipv6 address] remote [machine B ipv6 address] mode tun0
sudo ip link set dev tun0 up
sudo ip a add dev tun0 10.0.3.1
sudo ip route add 10.0.3.0/24 dev tun0
```

And on my remote machine (machine B):

```
sudo ip link add name tun0 type ip6tnl local [machine B ipv6 address] remote [machine A ipv6 address] mode tun0
sudo ip link set dev tun0 up
sudo ip a add dev tun0 10.0.3.2
sudo ip route add 10.0.3.0/24 dev tun0
```

And everything works great, I can ping each machine from the other over the tunnel.

However, when the machines reboot, the tunnels are lost, so I wanted to use netplan to manage them. So far I have been able to get netplan to create the interfaces properly with addresses:

```
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    tun0:
      mode: ipip6
      remote: "[machine B ipv6 address]"
      local: "[machine A ipv6 address]"
      addresses:
        - 10.0.3.2/32
      routes:
        - to: 10.0.3.0/24
          via: 10.0.3.1
```

However, no route is created. When I run `ip route`, I would expect to see `10.0.3.0/24 dev tun0 scope link` in the routing table but netplan is not creating it. How do I get netplan to create this route automatically so I don't have to run `sudo ip route add 10.0.3.0/24 dev tun0` every time?

Answer (score 0):

Your netplan config and your `ip` commands don't match: in the working command you are declaring the route on the device with no gateway, in the netplan you are declaring a gateway for the route but it is a gateway for which you do not already have a route.

You either need to declare your netmask such that 10.0.3.1 *is* in the route for the tunnel (i.e.: `10.3.0.2/30`, not `10.3.0.2/32`) or you need to declare the route as being `on-link`.

You should be able to check the output of `ip link` after setting up the tunnel both ways to compare whether they match.